# Selector in Method over riding

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the case of method over riding in objective c how selector knows that which method needs to call via selector?

As we dont pass any arguments in slector section...

Ex:
in `tmp.m` file 
There is 2 methods with different arguments

```
-(void)details
{

}

-(void)details:(NSDictionary *)result
{

}
```

And when m call another method with the use of selector as:

```
[mc detailstrac:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userID"] tracid:self.trac_id selector:@selector(details:)];
```

How selector knows to call which method !

I have checked that

```
-(void)details:(NSDictionary *)result
{
}
```

this method is called every time then what about

```
-(void)details
{
}
```

**this ?**

Comment: I think you got the solutions nw

Answer (score 3):

Selector will know on the basis how you call the method like from your example,

```
[mc detailstrac:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userID"] tracid:self.trac_id selector:@selector(details:)];
```

when you call @selector(details:) then the selector will call this method

```
-(void)details:(NSDictionary *)result { }
```

And When you call @selector(details) then the selector will call

```
-(void)details { }
```

The main difference here is **@selector(details)** and **@selector(details:)**.

Hope you understand my point!
Happy Coding!